# Simple SQL COUNT query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, ms-access-2007

I need to do it in MS Access. I have two tables:
`A {id, name, FK to B}`
`B {id, name, limit}`

Now I need to create query which would give me Bs that have less A than its limit:

```
SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.limit <
   (SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A WHERE A.[FK to B] = B.id)
```

I have no idea how can I make query simple as this in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do this with an `OUTER JOIN` and subquery instead:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM B 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Count(*) cnt, BID
        FROM A
        GROUP BY BID
    ) A ON B.Id = A.BID
WHERE B.limit < NZ(A.cnt,0)
```